# How does smackaho.st work?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

It basically sends everything you throw at it to your localhost. Is it possible to do this with apache server and .htaccess? Its also what I used as a callback url when I was developing using twitter's API. So I'm curious. http://smackaho.st

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no HTTP server involved here at all. The DNS A record for `smackaho.st` is 127.0.0.1, which refers to your own machine.

Using that name as a "callback url" probably won't work at all, since when Twitter tries to contact `smackaho.st`, they'll get 127.0.0.1, which refers to *their* own machine (not yours).

Comment: I used it as a callback url throughout development and it worked. Made tweets and uploaded images using it.

Comment: Maybe Twitter notices that you're asking them to contact 127.0.0.1, and instead of failing, they actually contact the real IP address from where the API connection is being made (since they also know that). It would sure reduce the number of support questions.